# How to process external url as different internally using htaccess rewriterule?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

New edit : In my wordpress localhost site , using .htaccess i am trying to tell server to process  links of format `https://example.com/store/foobar123` as  `https://example.com/store/product.php?p=foobar123` [so that server is able to process output of php code of `product.php` by grabbing the parameter `foobar`.  Note that visitor continues to see `https://example.com/store/foobar123` in his address bar but server should correctly  *internally* process this url as `https://example.com/store/product.php?p=foobar123`

I am an absolute beginner in htaccess stuff . i tried the below &many other codes from my limited understanding  below but it doesnt work/give the expected result :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^store/(.*)$ /store/product.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

What should be the htaccess code so that visitor on opening the link `https://example.com/store/foobar123` in address bar will continue to see `https://example.com/store/foobar123` there BUT the server will correctly interpret this request *internally* as `https://example.com/store/product.php?p=foobar123`  and display php output of codes in file `product.php` by grabbing the value `foobar` of parameter `p`  and show result to visitor on the page

***New more edit 1 *** : I also tried the below code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^store/(.*)$ store/product.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It doesnt work , if i visit `https://example.com/store/foobar123`  it gives error 403 Access forbidden/page not found

but if i visit `https://example.com/store/product.php?p=foobar123`  then this link open normally so i think it means i am making some mistake in above htaccess code. How do i  fix it

***New more edit 2 *** : I also tried the below code using this (tutorial)[https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#old-to-new] . it also gives access forbidden error/page not found error if i open `https://example.com/store/foobar123` . Note that i dont get error if i directly open `https://example.com/store/product.php?p=foobar123`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/store/(.*)$"  "/store/product.php?p=$1" [PT]
```

Comment: _“when visitor hovers his mouse over the link it should look as `https://example.com/store/foobar123`”_ - then you have to see to it, that the HTML code your system outputs, contains _that_ version to begin with. This part of the issue is not mod_rewrite’s responsibility.

Comment: @04FS, i am adding `https://example.com/store/product.php?p=` usign php infront of `foo` . If you were to edit my wordpress post you will just find decrypted version of `foo` in them. I have seen it at other sites done it, i just dont know how they are able to hide `product.php?p=`  . Also `foo` is an encrypted version of other urls

Comment: I don’t get what you mean here, but it doesn’t really matter either. If you want to status bar to show `https://example.com/store/foobar123` when I hover over a link, then _that_ must be the URL the `href` attribute of that link contains.

Comment: @04FS so you mean i have to use encryption to hide `product.php?p=` ? as you say mod_rewrite wont do what i need . I just want to hide/obfuscate `product.php?p=` from visitors

Comment: No, you have to make whatever creates your HTML, output the correct URLs you want your site visitors to see in the first place. Your HTML needs to link to `https://example.com/store/foobar123` - that is what the user will see, and what request will be send to the server. On the server side, this will then be rewritten to `/store/product.php?p=…` _internally_, for further processing. This is a two-step process, there are two places in which you need to change things.

Comment: @04FS thank you :) i think i am reaching close to the answer . Can you help me on this please. Now what i have done is rewritten all urls in html as `https://example.com/store/foobar123` so if i hover mouse over them or open in new tab , i can see it as `https://example.com/store/foobar123` But in new tab it gives error 403 access forbidden . How do i formulate htaccess so that server reads `https://example.com/store/foobar123` as `https://example.com/store/product.php?p=foobar123`  _internally_ & executes product.php

Comment: Your RewriteRule pattern above contains `[0-9]`, that is a character class matching the digits 0 to 9. You want it to match more than mere numbers though, `foobar123` – so you need to extend that character class accordingly.

Comment: @04FS thank u . I am just a beginner in this so i dont understand much of it. From what you say i need to find stuff that will match everything  not just numbers after `store/`. On searching around here & some google  , i found this `(.*) ` being said as it matches everything & since `foobar` includes letters,numbers,"=" sign & maybe more special characters i tried this `RewriteRule ^store/(.*)$ store/product.php?p=$1` but it gives error on opening `https://example.com/store/foobar123` i am pretty sure i am doing something wrong

Comment: With `(*.)`, it would match `product.php` again on the next round, so you’d get a redirect loop. You can try `([^.]+)` to match anything that doesn’t contain any dots.

Comment: @04FS with `([^.]+)` the wordpress page itself now doesnt open, site gives Error 500 Internal server error

Comment: So you are trying to _mix_ a WP setup, and your own routing here? That wasn’t really clear from your question. In that case, you probably need to be more specific what needs to be rewritten, and what needs to be left alone.

Comment: @04FS its wp setup on localhost xampp  , as a visitor if you visit a page there , Ex. `https://example.com/toys` , you will see hyperlinks on that page as `https://example.com/store/foobar123` . We are successful in hiding `product.php?p=` as per your earlier comments but now we want server to make sense that when a visitor clicks on `https://example.com/store/foobar123`  , the server should process this link _internally_ as `https://example.com/store/product.php?p=foobar123` while the visitor will continue to see `https://example.com/store/foobar123` in his browser

Answer (score 0):

If the original URL format is `https://example.com/store/product.php?p=foobar123` and you want to change it to `https://example.com/store/foobar123` then here is the rule you can use in your `public_html/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /store/product\.php\?p=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .+ /store/%1? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^store/((?!product\.php).+)/?$ /store/product.php?p=$1 [L,NC]
```

This  will map your new URL to the old  original one.

Comment: it didnt work , the url is still displayed as `https://example.com/store/product.php?p=foobar123`

Comment: thank you but its still the same ,being displayed as `https://example.com/store/product.php?p=foobar123` idk if this helps but i am on localhost wordpress

Comment: @simon Just put this code at the top of your htaccess before your WordPress rules otherwise those rules can override it.

Comment: @simon sorry for the late reply. Actually this should work if you type the original URL and this will then convert itto the new short format.  For example, `/store/product.php?p=foobar` will change to `/store/foobar` and show you the output of the original file.  Could you please be a bit more about the issues you are having with this rule? What exactly happens when you type the URL into your browser?

Comment: i have changed the question properly as per your response , can you please check it again .  After putting your code in .htaccess , if i hover mouse over hyperlink  , it shows as `https://example.com/store/product.php?p=foobar123`  but if i open this link in browser it opens as `https://example.com/store/foobar123` & gives error Object Not found.  i am testing it on `localhost/testsite`   so original link looks as `http://localhost/testsite/store/product.php?p=foobar123`  while the new link looks as `http://localhost/testsite/store/foobar123`   BUT it gives me error object not found

Comment: i have edited the question, can you please check it & let me know. Thank you